# Removing Cloudera Manager from server

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

Are there easy ways to remove the Cloudera Manager from a server without re-installing the entire OS? I accidentally installed a later version of CDH4 on a new DataNode that is supposed to join an older production cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Free/4.5.4/Cloudera-Manager-Free-Edition-Installation-Guide/cmfeig_topic_18.html). Why would you re-install the OS in order to do that?